# Prompt user to choose element from array for user information

Tags: java

So i'm trying to prompt the user to choose from an Array with Strings.
The rank is supposed to be added to the users attributes.

However when i print out the information for "rank" it's printing out the number, not the String. No idea why...

```java
String ranks[] = new String[3];
ranks[0] = "Guld";
ranks[1] = "Platinum";
ranks[2] = "Diamond";

System.out.println("\nVælg 1 for Guld");
System.out.println("Vælg 2 for Platiunum");
System.out.println("Vælg 3 for Diamond");

rank = input.next();
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing exactly what is relevant. Do you need the code where i add the information and subsequently print it out?

Comment: "No idea why..." and we as well, because we don't see the code which prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `rank` *is* just a number*. You need to use that number as an index to your array of `String`s:

```java
String rankName = ranks[rank - 1];
```

---

*****In fact, `Sanner#next()` returns a `String`. While this may contain a number, Java doesn't know this. You'll want to use [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) instead:

```java
int rank = input.nextInt();
```

---

As an aside, your block of `System.out.println()` statements could be shortened with a loop, since all the required information is already in your `ranks` array:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Vælg %d for %s\n", i + 1, ranks[i]);
}
```